# Do not allow the same number to be saved in the text box in vb6.0

Tags: vb6

When I save another inside a textbox , How to make the text box not accept saving the same number?

Comment: Can you provide a use case of how this feature would be used and how you want to either prevent input or alert the user about it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to filter a textbox?

You can use `KeyPress` event to read the user's input and perform some action based on it.  For example, you can cache previous inputs and create a pop-up if the user enters the same data twice.

See [this](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/prevent-bugs-by-filtering-input-in-vb6/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Using the KeyPress event, you can accomplish what you need.  The following example only allows numbers to be entered in addition to not allowing duplicate numbers:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
   'allow numbers and backspace
   If Not (KeyAscii >= 48 And KeyAscii <= 57) And Not KeyAscii = 8 Then KeyAscii = 0
   
   'but don't allow the same number twice
   If InStr(1, Text1.Text, Chr(KeyAscii)) > 0 Then KeyAscii = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: I want the code to be Private via a function or Sub

Comment: @AdnanSaeedBasalamah Perhaps you could clarify?  Obviously this is a Private Sub, so I'm not sure what you require.